# Why do my test files that are run after the first one have a time out error?

Tags: express, mocha.js

I am testing my express endpoints and any test file after the first one times out. They time out when trying to do a database operation.

I export my server object (in index.js) and in that file there are startup scripts that set up middleware, routes, the database connection, etc. I tried catching the errors at any code that operates on the database, but nothing is ever shown. I just know it times out when access the database. Maybe I am not closing it right or there is some race condition.

```
const { Student } = require('../../../models/student');

const mocksdk = require('../../firebaseMock');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const request = require('supertest');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

describe('authStudent Middleware', () => {

    let token;
    let server;

    before(async () => {
        server = require('../../../index');

        // Create a firebase user and get the token
        mocksdk.auth().autoFlush();
        mocksdk.auth().createUser({
            uid: '123',
            email: 'test@mail.com',
            password: 'test'
        });

        // Assign student role to user
        mocksdk.auth().setCustomUserClaims({ role: 0 });

        const user = await mocksdk.auth().getUser('123');
        token = await user.getIdToken();
    });

    after(async () => {
        await Student.deleteMany({});
        await mongoose.disconnect();
        await server.close();
    });

    it('should return 200 if the token is valid', async () => {
        const res = await request(server)
            .get('/students/me')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

        expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
    }); 
});
```

It times out in the after hook, when removing from the database and in the students/me endpoint when getting the user's information.

Edit: I tried increasing the timeout too and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a testSetup file. If a hook isn't in a describe block it is considered to be a root hook ([mocha docs](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks)). So in this testSetup, I put a before() and an after() hook, I required my index.js which runs the server and sets up the database in the before hook and exported the server (so it can be used in the actual test files). In the after, I closed my server and database connection. Now it seems to work, if there is a better way or there was a flaw in my initial code or this one, let me know.